# How to increase cpu quota for SQL Server Express in classic ASP script

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, cpu-usage, sql-server-express, iis-8

I have a classic ASP application with SQL Server Express that includes a couple of maintenance scripts that take potentially a few minutes to run. On the old Windows Server 2003 and 2008 installations, SQL Server Express would be capped at 50% of CPU during a long-running script, which was fine.

Recently I got a new machine with Windows 2012 Server, and on this one, SQL Server Express is capped at only 10% of CPU in long-running scripts. As a result, the new machine is marginally slower at running the scripts, despite being much more powerful. Is there a way to control and increase the CPU quota for SQL Server Express in this situation, to perhaps 25%?

I realize that SQL Server Express is limited to using 4 cores, but my new machine is only six cores, and the theoretical limit would seem to be 67% from this factor.

Where would this parameter be managed? Would it be a Windows setting, or a SQL Server Express setting, or an IIS setting that governs the CPU quota for a single script?

A couple of possibilities I think I have ruled out:

- IIS allows setting a limit on the CPU usage by an application pool, but this is not enabled by default, and was not enabled on my server.
- Windows has a utility called "Windows Server Resource Manager" but
  this also is not installed on my server.  In any case, it would only
  act when total CPU usage was above 70%, and I notice the apparent
  limitation on SQL Server Express even when the CPU is otherwise idle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not capped at a certain percentage. It is ONE CORE ONLY. Want more - get another version (i.e. not express).

> I realize that SQLExpress is limited to using 4 cores, but my new
>   machine is only six cores, and the theoretical limit would seem to be
>   67% from this factor.

Aha. Interesting.Where did you pick up that "knowledge"? It has never been that.

Comment: The four-core limit is mentioned in dozens of places, such as: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx